# Magento 2.3 - Can't translate product name

Tags: magento2, product, database, admin, localisation

After I upgrade my store to latest Magento 2.3.3 version, I can't translate Product Name in the Backend there is not any checkbox or something.

Like this is now:

[image]

[image]

So there is not anyway to translate the product name, not any "**Use Default Value**" checkbox. I keep a copy of my Old store and there the translation work and "**Use Default Value**" checkbox is there too:

[image]

Anyone have the same issue? Is there anyway to fix the problem?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you checked the scope of product name from Stores->Attributes->Product?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Admin Panel->Stores->Attributes->Products`

Search `name` in Attribute code column and edit product name attribute

Under `Advanced Attribute Properties` tab, change the scope value into Store view.

Clear the cache and check product edit form, now you can edit product name per store view.

Comment: was perfect, thank you very very much. Is work like a charm.